# Running DatabaseConfigUtility as Main class in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, ormlite

I am trying to create a **DatabaseConfigUtil** which extends **OrmLiteConfigUtil** in Android Studio. I followed the steps specified [here](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_4.html#Use-With-Android) but since it mentions steps to follow in Eclipse, I got lost in the middle.

```
public class DatabaseConfigUtility extends OrmLiteConfigUtil {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        writeConfigFile("ormlite_config.txt");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I tried to Edit configuration for the class still it throws an error because I have defined the path to the config file in my **DatabaseHelper** class

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "notes.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private Dao<Note, Integer> noteDao = null;
private RuntimeExceptionDao<Note, Integer> noteRunTimeDao = null;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION, R.raw.ormlite_config);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, ConnectionSource connectionSource) {
    try {
        // TableUtils.clearTable will create Table having attribute equals to Note class
        TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Note.class);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, ConnectionSource connectionSource, int i, int i2) {
    try {
        // first drop the table and then create the table again.
        TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, Note.class, true);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase, connectionSource);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Dao<Note, Integer> getNoteDao() throws SQLException {
    if (noteDao == null) {
        noteDao = getDao(Note.class);
    }
    return noteDao;
}

public RuntimeExceptionDao<Note, Integer> getNoteRunTimeDao() {
    if (noteRunTimeDao == null) {
        noteRunTimeDao = getRuntimeExceptionDao(Note.class);
    }
    return noteRunTimeDao;
}
```

}

The gradle execution fails and throws this error which is because I have declared the path to config file and it does not exist.

> Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
>   Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
>
> C:\Users\Pavitra\Documents\AndroidStudio\ORMLiteDemo\app\src\main\java\orm\entities\DatabaseHelper.java
>   Error:(24, 64) Gradle: error: cannot find symbol variable raw

**In order to create ormlite_config.txt file, I have to run the DatabaseConfigUtil class**.

**How to run the DatabaseConfigUtil to generate the ormlite_config.txt file?**

Any help or advice is much appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.